# Retained fragments and layout change crashes android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm working on an app with a team, that by default **sets retained to true** on all fragments.
I was trying to set up a portrait and landscape layouts for our tablet, the landscape having master/detail, and the portrait just having the master. Following the android guide on two pane layout, to check

```
if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
    // The detail container view will be present only in the
    // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
    // If this view is present, then the
    // activity should be in two-pane mode.
    mTwoPane = true;
}
```

If I go into landscape mode, select an item in master, I add the detail fragment with:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
        .commit();
```

If I then rotate to portrait, and the new layout file does is not have `item_detail_container`, then the app crashes with a message telling me there is no view to put the fragment in.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matthew.myapplication/com.example.matthew.myapplication.ItemListActivity}:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c006d
    (com.example.matthew.myapplication:id/item_detail_container) for fragment ItemDetailFragment{ea138c2 #0 id=0x7f0c006d}
```

Which is understandable - when the activity is recreated, the FragmentManager is trying to find the `FrameLayout` from when it was shown.

Things I know I can do to work around this:

1. stop retaining the detail fragment,
2. have the portrait layout also have that frame, set `twoPane` manually by checking for DP width, instead of using layout with DP qualifier.

Steps to recreate - Minimal complete example:

1. Open android Studio and create a new project with the activity "Master/Detail Flow"
2. In ItemDetailFragment#onCreateView, call `this.setRetainInstance(true);`
3. Open app on tablet or emulator in landscape mode and select any item, to display detail pane.
4. Rotate to portrait.

The app will crash.

I have seen this question asked before in the context of 'Nested Fragments', but I was unable to find a result specific to retained fragments.

Is there another option that would tell the OS to destroy my retained fragment if the frame is gone, or even to leave it but detach it - so that when I rotate back to landscape but didn't choose a new item, it plops it back into place?

Thanks for anyone's input.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need the fragment instance to be retained?

Comment: @NicRobertson no particular reason, just the whole existing app has a base class where everything is retained. it's more of looking for alternatives that might keep it that way, before I through a wrench in I have to document :-)